# how to set dynamic value for analytics-label in angular google analytics?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, google-analytics, analytics

I used angular material in my project, now I want to use angular-google-analytics. I have multi albums with their names, 
when I use `analytics-label="album.name_fa"`, GA return just string like 'album.name_fa' in GA panel not the value.

```
<md-button class="md-fab o black" aria-label="Play" ng-click="playAlbum(tracks)" analytics-on analytics-event="Play" analytics-category="Album" analytics-label="album.name_fa">
      <i class="icon icon-play icon-hc-3x"></i>
</md-button>
```

how can I have the value of `album.name_fa` in GA pannel as a result ?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a problem getting the right album.name_fa value, you should debug to check the value you are receiving first. Then, check if you goal is set up correctly in Google analytics Admin area ->View->Goal area like the image below
[image]

make sure you have the Label field empty. Check if your event is sending the right category, action and label values to GA.